# Custom post type navigation on static page

Tags: custom-post-types, pagination

I'm using the following code on a WP3.9 site to show a bunch of custom post types with pagination on a static page set as the frontpage:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'movie'
);
$paged = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;
$wp_query = new WP_Query( array_merge( $args, array('paged' => $paged) ) );
```

The first page is showing the correct info, but when I go to **domain.com/page/n/** I get redirected to **domain.com**.

If I add the following code to the functions.php file:

```
function disable_redirect_canonical( $redirect_url ) {
    $redirect_url = false;
    return $redirect_url;
}
add_filter('redirect_canonical','disable_redirect_canonical');
```

Then I can go to **/page/3/ and greater**, but **/page/2/** still redirects to the main page.

I'm really lost about this and I'm not really sure where to look to fix this problem.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit was the All in One SEO Pack plugin I'm using on the site. I had to disable the "Enable Advanced Options" in the "Custom Post Type Settings" section.